# Need help understanding code to count bits set to 1

Tags: c++, c

I came across [a StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/109025/978917) that gives the following code to efficiently count the number of bits that are set to `1` in a 32-bit `int`:

```
int NumberOfSetBits(int i)
{
    i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return (((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}
```

But I had lot of issues in understanding this. I couldn't find a link where it's
explained properly. Can anyone help me out here in understanding this piece of code, 
or provide a link which could be more helpful?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I count the number of zero bits in an integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244274/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-zero-bits-in-an-integer)

Comment: You should write down the binary representation of the constants used in the original code and see what it does if you run it, on paper. You do know what operators like `>>` do, right?

Comment: @MrLister right Shift operator

Comment: Explanation: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best algorithm to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Answer (score 1):

Answering somewhat indirectly: a great reference on how bit twiddling routines like this (and hundreds of others) work is the book "Hacker's Delight" by Henry Warren. I highly recommend it -- it belongs on every programmer's bookshelf. [http://www.amazon.com/Hackers-Delight-Henry-S-Warren/dp/0201914654](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201914654)